# Google drive "watch" API throws 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: push-notification, google-drive-api

When I try to execute following code :

gdrive.files().watch(filed.getId(), channel).execute();

Following exception is throwing. Other operations like file listing,upload etc.. is working perfectly. I also added the Domain and verified in SearchConsole to get push notification. Please let me know the issue.

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)

Comment: what scopes did you authorize?

Comment: I tried with both DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE and DriveScopes.All()

Comment: Please help to resolve this issue !!

Comment: Anybody who faced this issue and resolved same please post the solution...

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is about Authorization, you maybe missed an important step on fully authorizing your application, such as moving your client_secret.json to your working directory.

Follow the steps given by this [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name) :

> - Use this [wizard](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=drive&debugUI=DEVELOPERS)
>     to create or select a project in the Google Developers Console and
>     automatically turn on the API. Click Continue, then Go to credentials.
> - On the Add creadentials to your project page, click the Cancel button.
> - At the top of the page, select the OAuth consent screen tab. Select an Email address, enter a Product name if not already set, and click
>     the Save button.
> - Select the Credentials tab, click the Create credentials button and select OAuth client ID.
> - Select the application type Other, enter the name "Drive API Quickstart", and click the Create button.
> - Click OK to dismiss the resulting dialog.
> - Click the file_download (Download JSON) button to the right of the client ID.
> - Move this file to your working directory and rename it client_secret.json.

Comment: Followed these steps perfectly while creating the application. This doesn't resolve my issue. I can see my Http Header saying as HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error=invalid_token

Comment: what does the http request Authorization header contain?

Comment: Here is the sample Request  -------------- REQUEST  --------------                          
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/XYZIDOFFILE/watch
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: <Not Logged>
User-Agent: Test App Google-API-Java-Client Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.22.0 (gzip)
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 150

Comment: -------------- RESPONSE --------------
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,36,35"
Server: GSE
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error=invalid_token
Date: Fri, 30 Jun 2017 10:51:36 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Origin
Expires: Fri, 30 Jun 2017 10:51:36 GMT
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8